# py2exe gives EOFError

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe, eoferror

I have a simple program, I used pygame to import sound but it is still a CLI program.      Whenever I compile it into an exe it gives me an EOFError when I try to run it, It looks like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PlanetaryDistanceFromSun.pyw", line 57, in <module>
  File "PlanetaryDistanceFromSun.pyw", line 31, in main
  File "PlanetaryDistanceFromSun.pyw", line 44, in Planet
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here is the piece of code in question: raw_input("How far is %s from the sun? " % planet)

I did a fair amount of searching on the internet and found a few things that said I need a console argument, but I don't understand what that is.

Comment: What do you mean "I can't post properly written the code because of the formatting this the site uses"?  Formatting inside code blocks is preserved verbatim.

Comment: My fault, I'm new here and didn't know how that worked, I'll fix it

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280889/raw-input-causing-eoferror-after-creating-exe-with-py2exe?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [py2exe example](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) from the pygame website:

It also contains the solution to your problem:

> This will only work for GUI apps, change "windows =" to "console =" in setup command would do the job.

The relevant part is this (IIRC):

```
...
windows = [{
            'script': self.script,
            'icon_resources': [(0, self.icon_file)],
            'copyright': self.copyright
        }],
...
```

where you have to change `windows` to `console`.

Also, [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygame-users@seul.org/msg04832.html) on the pygame-user mailing list describes the same issue:

> My guess is that you used py2exe with the "windows" argument, meaning that no console is opened - without a console there is no stdin for raw_input to use. You can instead use the "console" argument in your setup.py, and your exe will open a console window allowing raw_input to work.